# AngularJS ui-mask doesn't work for number input

Tags: angularjs, regex

I need to have an input where it could be possible to write only numbers between 1-99 (only integer). How can I obtain this result without using JQuery (I need the "angular solution")?

This is my HTML code and I dont' understand why this doesn't work well.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="cdtirv" ng-model="elencoParametriBB.cdtirv" ng-keyup="modifica()" ui-mask="/^[1-9][0-9]?$"/>
```

Comment: Just to make sure: is there a closing `/"` in `ui-mask="/^[1-9][0-9]?$`?

Comment: I think so, but  the main problem is that in the view I see the regex expression... and not the empty (or properly enhanced) field..

Comment: It should most probably be  `ui-mask="^[1-9][0-9]?$"` or `ui-mask="/^[1-9][0-9]?$/"`. Else, the ui-mask does it differently. Try using `ng-pattern="/^[1-9][0-9]?$/"`

Comment: I had already tried with ng-pattern, but it doesn't work

Comment: "does not work" and "doesn't work well" are not helpful feedback. Why doesn't it?

Comment: You are right. The first "doesn't work well" means that the input box in the view shows exatly what I wrirte in the ui-mask, so I see /^[1-9][0-9]?$/. The second "does not work" means that I can write in the input whatever I want, infinite number of values and also letters or special characters